# falling star jquery animation

Tags: jquery

```
$('#sstar').animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
$('#sstar').animate({
        'backgroundPosition':'0px 0px','top':'30%', 'opacity':0
    }, 500);
```

css

```css
#sstar 
{
    position:absolute;
    left:2px;
    top:10;
    width:126px;
    height:80px;
    background:transparent url(../images/shootingstar.png) no-repeat 80px -200px;
    z-index:99999;
    opacity:0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

The animation is running very slow? How do I show it like a falling star?

Or give one example to show a falling star using jquery.

output should be something like this

[link](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-flash-1263712-shooting-star-over-city.php?st=b698399)

Comment: Surely you could just increase the speed by changing 500 to a lower value

Comment: i tried it...but not able to see any difference

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7rwZ7/)? By the way, when replying to comments please use `@` to notify.

Comment: @Sam i have show the output link .. i need something like that

Comment: @ShadowWizard  something like this http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-flash-1263712-shooting-star-over-city.php?st=b698399

Comment: @ShadowWizard your example enhanced : http://jsfiddle.net/7rwZ7/1/

Comment: @ShadowWizard but on right side!! that is opposite side

Comment: @ShadowWizard something similar to the output link given in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest thing is something like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="Background">
    <img src="http://www.com-geo.org/conferences/2011/images/presentations/deco/star_orange_20.png" id="Star" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#Background {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url(http://nightsky.org.uk/night_sky_pics/night_sky_1.jpg);
    width: 400px;
    height: 309px;
}

#Star {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
​
```

And the jQuery code is simply:

```
$('#Star').animate({"right": "360px", "top": "150px"}, 1500);​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/nkXZJ/1/).

This is using an image tag inside a container and animates the image position within the container.